# Testing each item in a list against every other item in the list in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to draw multiple circles on the form in visual basic under the condition that they do not overlap and do not appear inside each other. I have a function testing for that but it does not work 100% of the time. To elaborate, it NEVER makes the circles appear in a way where they overlap, however, sometimes the circles can appear with the exact same centre. This problem is giving me a headache and I have no idea how to solve this. It becomes especially bad if there are a lot of circles or if there are some really big ones (radius of 1000 plus). Interestingly if the radius of these circles is large, the form increases in size in order to give room for these circles to appear, however sometimes it still appears to choose the same centre for more than one circle!

For example if I give it 10 circles each with a radius of 1000, 5 of these will have the same centre and the form increases in size in order to give these circles room to appear without touching each other.

```
Public Function iteration() As Boolean
    Dim random_ As New Random
    Dim v1 As Single
    Dim v2 As Single
    Dim v3 As Single



    For Each circ1 As Circ In Circles
        For Each circ2 As Circ In Circles
            If Circles.IndexOf(circ1) <> Circles.IndexOf(circ2) Then
                Dim val As Single = ((circ2.y - circ1.y) ^ 2 + (circ2.x - circ1.x) ^ 2) ^ 0.5
                If circ1.R + circ2.R > val Then
                    While True
                        v1 = (random_.Next(minValue:=300, maxValue:=860))
                        v2 = (random_.Next(minValue:=300, maxValue:=860))
                        For Each circ3 As Circ In Circles
                            If circ2.R + circ3.R > ((v2 - circ2.y) ^ 2 + (v1 - circ2.x) ^ 2) ^0.5 Then
                                Exit For
                            End If
                            Dim cpos As Integer = Circles.IndexOf(circ2)
                            Circles(cpos) = New Circ(circ2.R, v1, v2)
                            Return False
                        Next
                    End While
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand your logic. Why do you compare the circles with themselves? If you add only new circles that do not overlap with already existing ones then there is not point to compare all the circles with themselves as there will never be an overlap.

You only must compare the new candidates to the already existing ones. Something like this:

```vb
Private Circles As List(Of Circ) = New List(Of Circ)
Private random_ As New Random

Public Function TryAddCircle() As Boolean
    Const NumberOfAttempts As Integer = 20

    Dim x, y, r As Single

    For i As Integer = 1 To NumberOfAttempts
        x = random_.Next(minValue:=300, maxValue:=860)
        y = random_.Next(minValue:=300, maxValue:=860)
        r = random_.Next(minValue:=10, maxValue:=300) 'Radius of new circle

        Dim overlapping As Boolean = False
        For Each c As Circ In Circles
            Dim distance As Single = ((c.x - x) ^ 2 + (c.y - y) ^ 2) ^ 0.5
            If distance <= c.R + r Then
                overlapping = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not overlapping Then
            Circles.Add(New Circ(r, x, y))
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

---

Make sure to not create a `Random` repeatedly. If the loop is fast enough, this can create the same random sequence repeatedly as `Random` is initialized with the current date/time and the PC clock ticks rather slowly compared to the CPU clock frequency.

If you are using .NET 6 or newer, you can use the automatically created instance of the [Random.Shared Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.shared) instead of creating a variable. E.g.:

```vb
x = Random.Shared.Next(minValue:=300, maxValue:=860)
```

---

Names like `v1`, `v2`, `val` or `iteration` are not great names. Is `v1` a vector, a velocity or something else? Probably they stand for "value", but doesn't any variable have a value? Iterations are used at many places. "iteration" does not reveal the purpose of the method. Instead, it only refers to an implementation detail which could change at any time. E.g. the iteration could be replaced by a recursion or a smart data structure.

Comment: `v1` is the first Velociraptor in the back yard!

Comment: Hi, firstly thank you for your comment, I am a beginner in visual basic so your feedback has been very insightful. Allow me to give more information about the problem. I need to create a way for the whole list of circles to appear randomly in different configurations each time. If I only check against the other circles, the setup will not be unique every time the button is pressed and hence not quite what we are looking for. I need it to check against the whole list to make sure that mistakes like same centre spawn do not happen. Thanks in advance!

Comment: My algorithm tests new circles against the whole list of circles and a new circle will never be added inside another circle. Neither with the same center nor somewhere else in another circle nor touch any other circle.

Comment: From your comment it seems to me that you want to add the same list of circles repeatedly to a larger list. But in your code I only see one single list. Also the list would have to be added with some x-y-offset, otherwise the new circles will always be centered in the already existing circles. I also don't see any offset being applied. So, this question is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, the solution offered in the first comment was good enough to solve the issue in the end. Taking the approach of pasting in one circle at a time in a predefined zone that can vary in size depending on the amount of circles was what did it for me. Thank you for the help!

Comment: This should really be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Ah that makes sense thanks! Yeah I just gave you the checkmark. If you're interested I went on to post a question on the next part of my problem somewhere on this page (you can probably find it by searching my profile or something lol)