# Reducing distance between a set of randomly generated circles using 'simulated gravity'

Tags: vb.net

I have a page of N randomly generated circles on a form. The circles can, but do not have to have varied radii. I have a page with a set of randomly placed circles on it. It is key to note that the set comes from user input. I now need to collect the circles together in order to create the most compact shape possible. I am thinking of simulating gravity in order to achieve this.

To provide some background before I give my function, in the data structure as well as providing each circle with x, y and r data, I also included an 'a' property (acceleration) which in my code is defined as 1/r. The a property will result in small circles having a small impact on the system and large circles having a big impact on the system. This 'a' property is what will hopefully give me the 'gravity' effect.

Here is my work so far, it draws a lines between all the centres and then it aims to reduce the distance between the centres. However, this is where my issues begin to appear since I cannot seem to present the new circles (either a mistake somewhere else or the position isn't actually being altered). Also I'm not too sure how to define which circle to take as circ1 and circ2, I mean due to the signs, my code may make it so that in fact the circles try to separate!

```
Public Sub gravitate()
    Dim pen As New Pen(Color.LimeGreen)
    Const NumberOfAttempts As Integer = 200
    GravitationalCircles.AddRange(SortedCircles)

    Dim overlapping As Boolean = False


    For Each circ1 As Circ In SortedCircles
        For Each circ2 As Circ In SortedCircles
            If circ1.x <> circ2.x And circ1.y <> circ2.y Then
                formGraphics.DrawLine(pen, circ1.x, circ1.y, circ2.x, circ2.y)
            End If
        Next
    Next

    For Each circ1 As Circ In SortedCircles
        For Each circ2 As Circ In SortedCircles
            Dim distance As Single
            Dim newcentrex_1 As Single
            Dim newcentrey_1 As Single
            Dim newcentrex_2 As Single
            Dim newcentrey_2 As Single
            If circ1.x <> circ2.x And circ1.y <> circ2.y Then
                distance = ((circ1.x - circ2.x) ^ 2 + (circ1.y - circ2.y) ^ 2) ^ 0.5
                newcentrex_1 = circ1.x + (circ1.a * distance)
                newcentrey_1 = circ1.y + (circ1.a * distance)
                newcentrex_2 = circ2.x - (circ2.a * distance)
                newcentrey_2 = circ2.y - (circ2.a * distance)


                For i As Integer = 1 To NumberOfAttempts
                    overlapping = False
                    For Each c As Circ In SortedCircles
                        distance = ((c.x - newcentrex_1) ^ 2 + (c.y - newcentrey_1) ^ 2) ^ 0.5
                        If distance <= c.R + circ1.R Then
                            overlapping = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    If Not overlapping Then
                        GravitationalCircles(SortedCircles.IndexOf(circ1)) = New Circ(circ1.R, newcentrex_1, newcentrey_1)
                    End If
                Next

                For i As Integer = 1 To NumberOfAttempts
                    overlapping = False
                    For Each c As Circ In SortedCircles
                        distance = ((c.x - newcentrex_2) ^ 2 + (c.y - newcentrey_2) ^ 2) ^ 0.5
                        If distance <= c.R + circ2.R Then
                            overlapping = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    If Not overlapping Then
                        GravitationalCircles(SortedCircles.IndexOf(circ2)) = New Circ(circ2.R, newcentrex_2, newcentrey_2)
                    End If
                Next

            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the things a bit compared to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77914949/880990). For instance I use a `System.Numeric.Vector2` for the circle centers and speeds and accelerations. This simplified the calculations, as this type has predefined functions for distance and other calculations and we need to have fewer variables.

I also add a `Velocity` and a `Mass` property to the circles:

```vb
Imports System.Numerics

Public Class Circle
    Public ReadOnly Property Radius As Single
    Public ReadOnly Property Mass As Single

    Public Property Center As Vector2
    Public Property Velocity As Vector2

    Public Sub New(radius As Single, center As Vector2)
        Me.Radius = radius
        Mass = radius * radius  'Proportional to the area of the circle
        Me.Center = center
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"M={Mass:n1}, C=({Center.X:n2}, {Center.Y:n2}, v=({Velocity.X:n3}, {Velocity.Y:n3})"
    End Function
End Class
```

I also create a Module `Space` for the creation of the circles and the calculations. It has a public property `Circles` and two public Subs `AddRandomCircles` (a polished version from my other answer) and `UpdatePositionsAndSpeeds`.

First you would call `AddRandomCircles` once and then repeatedly call `UpdatePositionsAndSpeeds` and draw the new positions and refresh the screen.

```vb
Module Space
    Public ReadOnly Property Circles As List(Of Circle)

    Public Sub AddRandomCircles(rectangle As RectangleF, minRadius As Single, maxRadius As Single, approxCount As Integer)
        For index = 1 To approxCount
            TryAddCircle(rectangle, minRadius, maxRadius)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function TryAddCircle(rectangle As RectangleF, minRadius As Single, maxRadius As Single) As Boolean
        Const NumberOfAttempts As Integer = 100

        For i As Integer = 1 To NumberOfAttempts
            Dim x = Random.Shared.NextSingle() * rectangle.Width + rectangle.Left
            Dim y = Random.Shared.NextSingle() * rectangle.Height + rectangle.Top
            Dim newCenter = New Vector2(x, y)
            Dim newRadius = Random.Shared.NextSingle() * (maxRadius - minRadius) + minRadius

            Dim overlapping = False
            For Each c As Circle In Circles
                If Vector2.DistanceSquared(c.Center, newCenter) <= (c.Radius + newRadius) ^ 2 Then
                    overlapping = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If Not overlapping Then
                Circles.Add(New Circle(newRadius, newCenter))
                Return True
            End If
        Next
        Return False
    End Function

    Private Function GetAcceleration(circle As Circle) As Vector2
        Dim acceleration As Vector2
        For Each otherCircle In Circles
            If otherCircle IsNot circle Then
                Dim distance = Vector2.Distance(circle.Center, otherCircle.Center)
                Dim a = Vector2.Normalize(otherCircle.Center - circle.Center) * otherCircle.Mass / distance
                acceleration += a
            End If
        Next
        Return acceleration
    End Function

    Public Sub UpdatePositionsAndSpeeds()
        Const DeltaTime As Single = 0.001

        For Each circle As Circle In Circles
            circle.Velocity += DeltaTime * GetAcceleration(circle)
            circle.Center += DeltaTime * circle.Velocity
        Next

        'Detect and handle collisions. Make sure to handle each pair of circles only once.
        For i = 0 To Circles.Count - 1
            Dim circle1 = Circles(i)
            For j = i + 1 To Circles.Count - 1
                Dim circle2 = Circles(j)
                Dim distance = Vector2.Distance(circle1.Center, circle2.Center)
                If distance <= circle1.Radius + circle2.Radius Then
                    'TODO: back off, so that r1 + r2 = distance (only fix positions)

                    'TODO: Adjust the velocities.
                    'See: What are elastic and inelastic collisions?: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/linear-momentum/elastic-and-inelastic-collisions/a/what-are-elastic-and-inelastic-collisions
                    'Let's use a non-elastic collision. This lets circles which collide stick together.
                    'See: Dynamic Circle-Circle Collision: https://ericleong.me/research/circle-circle/#dynamic-circle-circle-collision
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Note the constant `DeltaTime As Single = 0.001`. You can adjust it to increase or decrease the effect of gravity.

What is still missing from this little simulation is the detection of the collisions between the circles. We would still have to handle those somehow and then let the circles change their speeds accordingly.

Comment: Alright so I had a look at your code and I am wondering how are you approaching the problem here? We were thinking of making the 'gravity' act in small movements at a time and refreshing. I assume you have a different approach to it? Do you somehow do all of the calculations at the same time and find an answer?

Comment: `UpdatePositionsAndSpeeds` does one of these small movements. I have only shown the physics part but not shown the game-loop part or drawing part. Assuming that you are drawing the circles on `myControl` (could e.g. be a `Panel`), you could e.g. have a timer triggering the updates. In `Timer1_Tick` you would call `myControl.Invalidate()` and in `myControl_Paint` you would call `UpdatePositionsAndSpeeds` and then  draw the circles. If the circles are moving to fast or too slow, adjust `DeltaTime`.

Comment: Hi, so I tried some of your code and adapted it slightly to fit into what we need it to do. I think I mainly understand what you are trying to do and it's slowly but surely working which is great! We are now trying to implement circle collision and we are doing some experimenting.  I think that the elastic collisions are necessary in this case because if we did not use them and decided to stick the circles together, then the circles will not be able to move after contact - which we need them to do!

Comment: With a purely elastic collision the circles will never come to rest and bump eternally. Note that after a non-elastic collision, the circles are still moving but they are not bumping off each other but are still subject to the gravity of the other balls. They will continue moving together. Maybe the best would be to apply both types of collision with a certain percentage.

Comment: Maybe we could try putting some kind of centre of gravity in the system as well so that not only are the circles all attracted to each other but also to a main 'attractor', we need to find a way for any excess momentum to be lost. At the moment when the circles collide they obtain a velocity in opposite directions from the momentum change. This is because I made a step like : 'If the circles overlap, then minus that velocity.' However this results in a reverse movement. We need to make sure that collision works properly and then we need to think about settling the system down.

Comment: Quick update, I tried inelastic collisions where velocities are not changed and you were right - it ends up in an infinite loop of them gravitating and being pushed away from each other. We need a way for the velocities to be updated reasonably.

Comment: The simplest way to achieve this is to reduce the calculated velocities after a collision. E.g.: `v *= 0.9f;`. This makes the system lose energy. It may not be physically correct, but if it looks good, why not? Adding yet another gravity source will not reduce the total energy of the system.

Comment: Hi, so I added in a velocity update by taking the momentum equation and rearranging it. Like you say in this case it doesn't need to be particularly physically accurate but physics is what im good at so I went with that. I have a small bug with overlapping circles sometimes that I need to fix and I want to display my final product in the middle of the page. I am wondering whether a centre of gravity in the centre of the form will yield better results than before? I mean sometimes the cluster formed isn't quite what we're looking for!

Comment: I could imagine that the whole cluster of circles is sometimes drifting away from the center because of numerical issues. A artificial gravity center in the center of the form could fix that. Btw., I would only fix the positions when there is a overlap, not the velocities. The velocities are a matter of elastic and non-elastic collision calculations.

Comment: So a quick update on what we've done: we fixed an artificial singularity in the centre and we are working on some debugging. I feel like if we keep pushing in this direction we should have a situation where all the circles are interacting with each other AND are attracted to the singularity. The singularity has NO collision - this way one of the centres will align itself on the singularity and (hopefully) all the other circles will group around it - resulting in the tight cluster which we want to see.